# Qt Disable Not Responding timeout?

Tags: c++, qt, loops, timeout

In my project, I have a lot of loops making many calculations that can take quite some time. Everything runs fine until I get an error while it's loading. When it's calculating everything, my program becomes "Unresponsive" until it is finished loading. It seems there is some sort of timer and when it reaches 60 seconds, the debugging stops and I get this error:

```
Exception at 0x7585b9bc, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) in Qt5Cored!QTimer::isSingleShot
```

Is there any way to disable that responsiveness timer?

Thanks for your time :)

EDIT: Here is the loop. It's awfully abstract so I apologize that you don't know the full context of this loop. :/  But know this, the program doesn't freeze at the exact same point in time. Sometimes when i== 498, sometimes 499. etc.

```
   for(int i=0; i<=728; i++)
    {
        int sections;
        if(PCBRchunks[i] != "Null")
        {
            QString blockId;
            PCBRblocks[i].fill('0', 131072);

            //Get number of sections
            temp_hex = PCBRchunks[i].mid(PCBRchunks[i].indexOf("09000853656374696f6e73")+30, 2);
            HexToInt2(temp_hex, temp_int);
            sections = temp_int;

            int totalStart;
            totalStart = PCBRchunks[i].indexOf("070006426c6f636b7300001000")+26;

            for(int s=0; s<=sections-1; s++)
            {
                int y;
                temp_hex = PCBRchunks[i].mid(totalStart + (s*20604) + 20574, 2);
                HexToInt2(temp_hex, y);

                for(int k=0; k<=255; k++)
                {
                    for(int p=0; p<=15; p++)
                    {
                        blockId = PCBRchunks[i].mid(totalStart + (s*20604) + (p*512) + ((((k-((k/16)*16))*16)+(k/16))*2), 2);
                        if(y<8)
                            PCBRblocks[i].replace((p*2)+(k*256)+(y*32), 2, blockId);
                        else
                            PCBRblocks[i].replace((p*2)+(k*256)+((y-8)*32)+65536, 2, blockId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(PCBLchunks[i] != "Null")
        {
            QString blockId;
            PCBLblocks[i].fill('0', 131072);

            //Get number of sections
            temp_hex = PCBLchunks[i].mid(PCBLchunks[i].indexOf("09000853656374696f6e73")+30, 2);
            HexToInt2(temp_hex, temp_int);
            sections = temp_int;

            int totalStart;
            totalStart = PCBLchunks[i].indexOf("070006426c6f636b7300001000")+26;

            for(int s=0; s<=sections-1; s++)
            {
                int y;
                temp_hex = PCBLchunks[i].mid(totalStart + (s*20604) + 20574, 2);
                HexToInt2(temp_hex, y);

                for(int k=0; k<=255; k++)
                {
                    for(int p=0; p<=15; p++)
                    {
                        blockId = PCBLchunks[i].mid(totalStart + (s*20604) + (p*512) + ((((k-((k/16)*16))*16)+(k/16))*2), 2);
                        if(y<8)
                            PCBLblocks[i].replace((p*2)+(k*256)+(y*32), 2, blockId);
                        else
                            PCBLblocks[i].replace((p*2)+(k*256)+((y-8)*32)+65536, 2, blockId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(PCTRchunks[i] != "Null")
        {
            QString blockId;
            PCTRblocks[i].fill('0', 131072);

            //Get number of sections
            temp_hex = PCTRchunks[i].mid(PCTRchunks[i].indexOf("09000853656374696f6e73")+30, 2);
            HexToInt2(temp_hex, temp_int);
            sections = temp_int;

            int totalStart;
            totalStart = PCTRchunks[i].indexOf("070006426c6f636b7300001000")+26;

            for(int s=0; s<=sections-1; s++)
            {
                int y;
                temp_hex = PCTRchunks[i].mid(totalStart + (s*20604) + 20574, 2);
                HexToInt2(temp_hex, y);

                for(int k=0; k<=255; k++)
                {
                    for(int p=0; p<=15; p++)
                    {
                        blockId = PCTRchunks[i].mid(totalStart + (s*20604) + (p*512) + ((((k-((k/16)*16))*16)+(k/16))*2), 2);
                        if(y<8)
                            PCTRblocks[i].replace((p*2)+(k*256)+(y*32), 2, blockId);
                        else
                            PCTRblocks[i].replace((p*2)+(k*256)+((y-8)*32)+65536, 2, blockId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(PCTLchunks[i] != "Null")
        {
            QString blockId;
            PCTLblocks[i].fill('0', 131072);

            //Get number of sections
            temp_hex = PCTLchunks[i].mid(PCTLchunks[i].indexOf("09000853656374696f6e73")+30, 2);
            HexToInt2(temp_hex, temp_int);
            sections = temp_int;

            int totalStart;
            totalStart = PCTLchunks[i].indexOf("070006426c6f636b7300001000")+26;

            for(int s=0; s<=sections-1; s++)
            {
                int y;
                temp_hex = PCTLchunks[i].mid(totalStart + (s*20604) + 20574, 2);
                HexToInt2(temp_hex, y);

                for(int k=0; k<=255; k++)
                {
                    for(int p=0; p<=15; p++)
                    {
                        blockId = PCTLchunks[i].mid(totalStart + (s*20604) + (p*512) + ((((k-((k/16)*16))*16)+(k/16))*2), 2);
                        if(y<8)
                            PCTLblocks[i].replace((p*2)+(k*256)+(y*32), 2, blockId);
                        else
                            PCTLblocks[i].replace((p*2)+(k*256)+((y-8)*32)+65536, 2, blockId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        qDebug() << i;
        ui->progressBar->setValue((i*100)/729);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not within Qt, it's in the operating system. The best solution is to perform your work in a worker thread so that UI thread can process messages in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

It is a general practice to establish worker threads for heavy computations not to get the UI unresponsive. The worker thread would be decoupled from the main ui thread for that reason.

Here you can find an article with very complete explanation and examples how to create a thread class in general, even though you could use `std::thread` with C++11:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21114/Creating-a-C-Thread-Class

Here you can find an article with very complete explanation and examples how to create worker threads:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/552/Using-Worker-Threads

Hope, it helps.

Comment: So I have gotten my loop in a thread and everything is hooked up, however I have no clue as to how to pass my variables from my main program to the thread. I'm starting my thread from my main program using cThread.start(); and that automatically starts my run() function. How can I send variables to and from the thread?

Comment: mc360pro: I do not understand the question. You do not send variables to and from a thread.

Comment: ? Then what will my thread do? I figured the thread just does what I need it to do seperately then return those "changed" variables?

Comment: I made my thread based on this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PR6wVy7Et1A

Comment: mc360pro: You seem to have created a separate thread for that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680482/qt-pass-variables-to-thread Anything else in this thread not covered by other, or you can select an answer?

Comment: ow did that happen? I was writing the question, then closed out of the page thinking I deleted it. I had no idea that it posts the question anyways? I canceled it because I saw that you commented.